# IndexError: How come this index out of range despite it seemingly lining up correctly?

Tags: python

I was trying to use a for loop to fill an array using a return value from another function.

```
def test_weights():
    w1 = 0.25
    w2 = 0.5
    w3 = 0.75
    w4 = 1
    w5 = 1.25
    weights = [w1, w2, w3, w4, w5]
    mse_array = []

    for i in range(len(weights)):
        mse_array[i] = prob3(weights[i])
```

The compiler returned

**mse_array[i] = prob3(weights[i])**

**IndexError: list assignment index out of range**

I'm not sure how this is out of bounds since i starts at 0, it should line up correctly with the arrays, and not go out of bounds since it is the range of len(weights).

prob3(x) is a function that returns a float when given a value. What could be the issue? Thank you!

Comment: Better to use `for weight in weights` if you don't need the list index, or use `for index, weight in enumerate(weights)` if you do need the index, than to use `for i in range(len(weights))`.

Comment: Your entire code could be: `mse_array = [prob3(x) for x in [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty list (mse_array) cannot be used while using indexes.
Working with Lists there is the append() function or you can simply use the '+' notation if the function also **returns a list**

```
def test_weights():
    w1 = 0.25
    w2 = 0.5
    w3 = 0.75
    w4 = 1
    w5 = 1.25
    weights = [w1, w2, w3, w4, w5]
    mse_array = []

    for i in range(len(weights)):
        mse_array.append(prob3(weights[i])) ## modified line
```